# Logistic regression with small and differing sample sizes

Tags: logistic, sas, small-sample, methodology

I asked this question on Stack Overflow and was encouraged to come here for more help regarding methodological limitations.

Previous question: I ran the model in SAS and I can't make sense of the results. My first question- does it matter that the groups are quite different in size AND the sample size is small? The total sample size excluding missing values is 57, with 13 in Group 3, 18 in Group 2, 26 in Group 1.

I believe the best path is a multinational logistic regression. Am I missing something that would lead to another test being utilized?

The independent variable is social support-- continuous and ranging from 1.10 to 4 in 0.10 increments. The outcome variable is sleep quality that has been combined into 3 separate groups -- categorical.

Other information: the sleep variable is ordinal and is measured by a categorization of the sum of multiple data points.

I know that in general the sample size is a limitation, as well as the variation among groups. Are there any other major limitations that I should look out for/make sure to state in the discussion?

Thank you in advance!

Some edits:
The sleep variable is categorized into 3 groups by the PI. There are originally 9 data points collected as "sleep" variables (all ordinal 1-3), which she combined into 1 overall sleep variable comprised of 1, 2, or 3.

The model that I have fitted is a multinomial logisitic regression in SAS using proc logistic model.  model socialsupport = sleepdummy2 sleepdummy3;

The reference group is the "sleepdummy1"

My goal is to see if social support is associated with the sleep variable.

Comment: Please provide more specific statistical details on the model you have in mind and/or what model you have already fit but cannot make sense of. How do your three groups of size 13, 18, and 26 come into play? Are these the sleep quality groups that you refer to later in your question or does this describe a separate grouping? Why does sleep quality have to be categorized at all? I *think* you have the following: 57 observations of an ordinal outcome $Y\in\{1,2,3\}$ and a predictor $X\in\{1.1,1.2,\ldots,4\}$, where 13 of the Y's are in group 3, 18 are in group 2, and 26 are in group 1.

Comment: @psboonstra The sleep variable is categorized into 3 groups by the PI. There are originally 9 "sleep" data pts which she combined into 1 overall sleep variable comprised of 1, 2, or 3. You are correct in your interpretation of my rambling!

The model that I have fitted is a multinomial logisitic regression in SAS using proc logistic model.  model social = slpdummy2 slpdummy3;
Reference cat. of slpdummy1. 

My goal is to see if social support is associated with the sleep variable which I think I've achieved. I'm concerned about the potential limitations that I may be missing . Thank you!